# How to set a different value in the generator meta tag?

Tags: actions

I know that you can remove the following line from the WordPress source code:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.2" />
```

But instead of removing the tag completely, I just want to change its value. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is no hook there to change the texts on the fly. So the way is like below:

Let's first remove the default one, use the following code in `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
```

Now show our new one, add the following code in `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_custom_generator_meta_tag() { 
   echo '<meta name="generator" content="Mr. Kauwa Kala" />' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_custom_generator_meta_tag' );
```

Comment: That's what I wanted!

Comment: You have to use `. "\n"` in order to include a new line, as I wrote before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target the `xhtml` type generator, you can use the `the_generator` filter:

```
/**
 * Change the version number to PI for the 'xhtml' type generator
 */
add_filter( 'the_generator', function ( $html, $type )
{
    if( 'xhtml' === $type )
        $html = sprintf( '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress %f"/>', M_PI );
    return $html;
}, 10, 2 );
```

or the `get_the_generator_{$type}` filter:

```
/**
 * Change the version number to PI for the 'xhtml' type generator
 */
add_filter( 'get_the_generator_xhtml', function ( $html )
{
    return sprintf( '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress %f"/>', M_PI );    
} );
```

Other types are `html`, `atom`, `rss2`, `rdf`, `comment` and `export`. They do not all use the same HTML structure.

But I doubt it will do much for security, if that's the reason for changing it.